# Globally matching name value pairs without a seperator between them

Tags: regex, perl, key-value

I have the following formatted sample string:

```
== header == information about things ==headeragain== info can have characters like.*?{=
```

etc on just one line.

I want to parse this in to a hash such that the keys are the "==.+?==" and the values are the info after the keys. I've tried a couple of regular expressions to globally match these pairs:

```
%hash = $string =~ /(==.+?==)(.+)/g
```

and

```
%hash = $string =~ /(==.+?==)(.+?)/g
```

Will match the first key and then everything else as its value, and match just the keys respectively.

```
%hash = $string =~ /(==.+?==)(.+(?===.+?==))/g
```

is supposed to look ahead for the next key, but not "eat it up" as I understand it. However, it will only match the first pair and go no further.

I think this problem has come from a misunderstanding of how the global modifier acts. Do I need to tweak something in one of my expressions? Or do I need to be doing something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're using non-greedy modifier, there's no limitation for 2nd subgroup in you 2nd example.

Add positive look-ahead: `(?=$|==)` after value. Here `(?=` is a declaration of look-ahead block and `$` or `==` is a substring, you're searching for.

I.e. the solution is: `/(==.+?==)(.+?)(?=$|==)/g`

Comment: Thanks, the lookahead for "$" to get last pair is what I needed! A little silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($line =~ /
   == \s*
   ( .+? )
   \s* == \s*
   ( .*? )
   (?= \s* (?: == | \z ) )
/xg) {
   my $key = $1;
   my $val = $2;
   ...
}
```

But I dislike using the "`?`" quantifier modifier. It doesn't actually prevent the wrong thing from being matched when given wrong or unexpected input. So I'd use:

```
while ($line =~ /
   == \s*
   ( \S (?: (?! \s* == ). )* )
   \s* == \s*
   ( (?: (?! \s* == ). )* )
/xg) {
   my $key = $1;
   my $val = $2;
   ...
}
```

Comment: `(?:(?!PAT).)*` is to `PAT` as `[^CLASSES]` is to `[CLASSES]`.